# Non-animating banner ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm using Admob to display smart banner ads in my Android puzzle game and I've received some user complaints that the banner animations are distracting (they're mostly simple text animations, not full video). I've noticed other puzzle games that seem to display only static, non-animating banners (often exact copies of my own ads, apart from being static).

So, is there some way to ask Admob to only serve static banners, or is there some other ad network with this option?

Comment: Not an answer, but another reason to try remove them: I found animating banner ads to be the primary source of battery drain in one of my apps.